# PHP function printer_list working inside Eclipse but not on command line

Tags: php, eclipse, windows, printing

I have a strange problem.
I use Eclipse Luna 4.4.0 on my Windows 7 professional machine to develop a CLI PHP program called mytest.php.

The program for now is just very simple:

```
<?php
    var_dump(printer_list(PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL));
?>
```

php_printer.dll is installed under php\ext directory.

If I run this directly in Eclipse I can see an array of 4 printers in the 'Debug Output' view. But if I run same php file in a DOS console on same server like:

C:>php mytest.php

then it shows nothing!?!

Why I cannot get the printer list if I call my program from console?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I found it by myself.
Eclipse run a different PHP version (5.5.14) than the DOS box.
If I set the path to the correct php.exe in the console window than it works fine!